# Using Div Tags to Organise HTML elements in CSS - Where did I go wrong with implementing fonts for certain classes?

Tags: html, css

I started with HTML and CSS earlier today, and having just learnt about Divs, Classes and ID's, I started to implement them in a little test project I have.

However, when I tried to use two classes to set fonts (using Google Fonts), I must have gone wrong as they aren't visible on the finished version whatsoever.

Here is the HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
<div id="heading">
<h1> Page Title </h1>
</div>
<div id="subheading">
<h2> Page Subtitle </h2>
</div>
</div>

<div class="description">
<p> Page Description </p>
</div>

<div class="reasons">
<div id="title">
<h3> Why us? </h3>
</div>

<div id="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div id="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

<div id="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div id="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

 <div id="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div id="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

</div>




</body> 
</html>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.reasons{
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.heading{
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

*{
text-align: center;
}


h1 {
color: #696969;
font-size:3em;
}

h2 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:2.5em;
margin:0;
}

h3 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:2em;
margin:0.2;
}

h4 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:1.5em;
margin:0;
}

p {

font-size:1em;
margin:0;
}
```

Can one of you guys please explain where I went wrong? I understand this is probably a very basic mistake, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you seem a little mixed up with IDs and Classes. IDs should be unique (only one tag in your HTML with that ID). Classes can be applied to multiple things. IDs are referenced in CSS as # and classes as ..

Changing your IDs to classes made the fonts show up for me.

```css
.reasons{
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}

.heading{
font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

*{
text-align: center;
}


h1 {
color: #696969;
font-size:3em;
}

h2 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:2.5em;
margin:0;
}

h3 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:2em;
margin:0.2;
}

h4 {
color: #fffff0;
background-color: #CD5C5C;
font-size:1.5em;
margin:0;
}

p {

font-size:1em;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
<div class="heading">
<h1> Page Title </h1>
</div>
<div class="subheading">
<h2> Page Subtitle </h2>
</div>
</div>

<div class="description">
<p> Page Description </p>
</div>

<div class="reasons">
<div class="title">
<h3> Why us? </h3>
</div>

<div class="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div class="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

<div class="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div class="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

 <div class="title">
<h4> Statement </h4>
</div>

<div class="text">
<p> Proof </p>
</div>

</div>




</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea why it did work? I'm still a little confused, but made the changes so it's all good!

Comment: Sorry, changing the others into classes too, seeing as reasons and title were already set as a class in the HTML?

Comment: Some of them were already working for me. Heading was the broken one.

Comment: Oh yeah definitely, I just wanted to clarify first! Thanks :)